# PHPUnit 7: Failed asserting that exception of type \InvalidArgumentException is thrown

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this code:

```
public function method(){
  //...
  if(!$exist) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Ce client inexistant', 400);
  }
}
```

I do the UT of this code:

```
public function methodTest(){
      //...
      if(!$exist) {
          $this->expectExceptionMessage("Ce client inexistant");
          $this->expectException("\InvalidArgumentException");
      }
    }
```

It displays an error message

> Failed asserting that exception of type "\InvalidArgumentException" is
>   thrown.

I don't know where is the error in my code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solve my problem. This is the code:

```
$this->throwException(new \InvalidArgumentException('Ce client inexistant', 400));
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where is this a solution for your problem? Yes, you force the test to throw the expected exception, however the problem is that the "real" exception isn't thrown/catch. So I would say it's a workaround for passing the test, but no solution for the actual problem. #nooffence

Answer (score 1):

For those who faced this issue, try this:

```
    $this->expectException(Exception::class);

    $client = self::createClient();
    $client->catchExceptions(false);

    $client->request(...);
```